# How to I make exception in exception when catching errors in python?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, exception, error-handling

So, I have this code, works very fine, but I want to have possibility if I input x it will return me to the beginning of choosing list I have

```
def ask2():
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input('Pick a number in range 1-100: '))
    except ValueError:  # just catch the exceptions you know!
        print('That\'s not a number!')
    else:
        if 1 <= number <= 100:  # this is faster
            print("added")
        else:
            print('Out of range. Try again')
```

Comment: `finally` ? https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-341.html

Comment: Then when I add finally it says local variable number might be referenced before assignment

Comment: initialize the variable before

Comment: I would just put "continue" where you print "added" to break out of the while True. However, since it's inside a function, you can use "return" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Guido van Rossum spent some time working with Java, which does
>   support the equivalent of combining except blocks and a finally block,
>   and this clarified what the statement should mean*:

```
try:
    block-1 ...
except Exception1:
    handler-1 ...
except Exception2:
    handler-2 ...
else:
    else-block
finally:
    final-block
```

> The code in `block-1` is executed. If the code raises an `exception`, the
>   various except blocks are tested: if the exception is of class
>   `Exception1`, `handler-1` is executed; otherwise if it's of class
>   `Exception2`, `handler-2` is executed, and so forth. If no exception
>   is raised, the `else-block` is executed.
>
> No matter what happened previously, the `final-block` is executed once
>   the code block is complete and any raised exceptions handled. Even if
>   there's an error in an exception handler or the `else-block` and a new
>   exception is raised, the code in the `final-block` **is still run**.

---

[PEP 341: Unifying try-except and try-finally](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0341/)